# How to SendMessage

Tags: c++, windows, forms, console, sendmessage

I have a problem. I want in my program(follow code) have 2 windows: console and empty form to output graphics. And from my func main send messages to form to draw shapes. Input data to console. But func SendMessage() doesn't work. What wrong?

```
int main()
{
 char szClassName[] = "CG_WAPI_Template";
 HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
 HINSTANCE hInstance = NULL;
 MSG lpMsg;

 if(!AllocConsole())
  MessageBox(NULL, "Failed to create the console!", "Ошибка", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK);

  void *h_inc = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
  void *h_out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

  WNDCLASS wc;
 /*wc.style       = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
 wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
 ...
*/


 if(!RegisterClass(&wc))
 {MessageBox(NULL, "Не могу зарегистрировать класс окна!", "Ошибка", MB_OK);
  return 0;
 }

 hWnd = CreateWindow(...); 

 ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_MAXIMIZE); 
 UpdateWindow(hWnd);

 char buf[2];
 unsigned long lengh;
 ReadConsole(h_inc,buf,1,&lengh,NULL);

 SendMessage(hWnd, WM_USER+2, 0, 0); 

 if(GetMessage(&lpMsg, NULL, 0, 0))  
 {
  TranslateMessage(&lpMsg);
  DispatchMessage(&lpMsg);
 }

 ReadConsole(h_inc,buf,1,&lengh,NULL);

 if (!FreeConsole())
  MessageBox(NULL, "Could not free the console!", "Ошибка", MB_OK);

 return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What's the error from SendMessage?

Comment: No error - the program hang up and case of message does not execute.

Answer (score 1):

SendMessage function does not return until the message is processed by the window. You need to have an event loop in order to handle messages. Look fo r a tutorial [here](http://www.infernodevelopment.com/c-win32-api-tutorial).

In your event loop you will have to handle messages for two windows: for the console window and for the GUI winodow. For the console messages you will need to handle the key press events, and send your custom message (WM_USER + X) to the GUI window.

Comment: Not true. SendMessage calls the window procedure directly, it doesn't go on the queue. You most certainly do not need multiple event loops.

Comment: Yeh, not multiple event loops, but handle two windows in the event loop. In the code snippet the OP provided the he sends a custom user message: `SendMessage(hWnd, WM_USER+2, 0, 0);` which procedure will be called for this message?

Comment: the window procedure for hWnd gets called directly. It's synchronous. What's more that message loop can handle as many different window handles as you care to create. That is the canonical message loop as used by millions of programs since the dawn of time (well, Windows 1.0 in 1985 at least)!

Comment: The handles of console and form are the same! because one program has two windows. Can you give me the example of code, I do not imagine precisely - how does it look like.

Comment: @kill: what do you mean they are the same? you just dont keep the handle to the console window, you overwrite it with the handle to the GUI window.